# Formulation of a sentence using FOL

Tags: logic, knowledge-representation

I want to formulate the following sentence using FOL; I want also to know whether there any contradictions in it, or if it is consistent.

Assuming human relations are binary:

> All Human Relations are Utilitarian (Human relations are Utilitarian
>   only when people in those relations are selfish and calculative).
>   I am a human. People are Humans. Unselfish people are nice. Therefore, I am nice.

Comment: I don't know about FOL, but there is no guarantee that selfish people are bad. It is ultimately determined by collective good or bad.

Comment: There's a contradiction: either all relations are utilitarian, or they are not; but not both. The second sentence thus contradicts the first, unless all people are selfish and calculative. And in the remaining sentences you establish that there is at least one person that is not selfish.

Comment: 1. ∀ r HumanRelations(r) ->  Utilitarian(r)
2. ∃ r Utilitarian(r)-> Selfish(People(p,r)) ∧ Calculative(People(p,r))
3. Human(I)
4. ∃ p People(p) - > Human(p)
5. ~Selfish(p) -> Nice(p)
6. Nice(I) , can someone verify?